# Curve fitting between two numbers

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to curve fit between two values with the curve being that of `x^3` where `0> x <1`  so that the values of `y` increase gradually and then increase exponentially as approaching 1.

For example, I have a low figure of 100 and high figure of 1000, I would like to map this to a curve of x^3, and be able to select 6 values equally spaced: `[100, y1, y2, y3, y4, 1000]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a cubic curve `x^3` or do you want an exponential curve? These aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
def curved(n, start, rnge, exp):
   r = ((n - start) / rnge) ** exp
   return start + r * rnge

for n in [100, 280, 460, 640, 820, 1000]:
  print(curved(n, 100, 900, 3)) #=> 100.0, 107.2, 157.6, 294.4, 560.8, 1000.0
```